# setState while scrolling makes scrolling laggy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm using setState inside a function that triggers every time you scroll to get the `offSet` value to be used in a certain calculation. I have noticed using setState while scrolling makes the scrolling lag very much and it's not smooth whatsoever. How could I make the scrolling smooth while doing my calculation as well?

**my function**

```
    /**
     * @override
     */
    onWidgetScroll(e) {
        const myDiv = document.getElementById('myScroll');
        this.setState({
            offSet: myDiv && Math.abs(myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top) + 60,
        });
    }
```

**Container** is something like this with many components inside.

```
<div>
     <div id="myScroll">
          /*Other components*/
     </div>
</div>
```

Without the setState, the scrolling is much smoother. Using setState makes it lag.

Comment: Well, I can understand at least why it's lagging. Calling `getBoundingClientRect()` on a DOM element is a [relatively slow operation](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/resize-observer/issues/5) and setState will rerender parts of the DOM, which would also cause noticeable lag. What is the goal of the calculation? What exactly are you wanting to do with `onWidgetScroll`?

Comment: @ChristopherBradshaw The div i'm scrolling has a list of cards. I want to show which card is in view now. For that i'm doing a calculation using offset , card width and height etc.

Comment: First, use React refs and not `getElementById` it's not the way in React.second,  you can debounce your scrolling handler if it doesn't break the ux/ui.

Comment: @gaditzkhori i have debounced also. But same result

Comment: Can you share working example in codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I have the same problem and I use react ref  to identity  the element in the DOM